# aligning text in a cell of a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How to vertically align short stack in a cell of a table?
I am using "\shortstack" and would like it vertically centred in the cell of a table

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

With a `\Centerstack` of the `stackengine` package, you can just use a normal `c` column of `tabular`.  In the MWE below, I additionally horizontally-align columns to the right, left, and center, using the optional argument of `\Centerstack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
\hline
\Centerstack[r]{1\\ 22\\3\\444}
&
\Centerstack[l]{1\\22}
&
\Centerstack{1\\2\\333}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `m{width}` column type from `array` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{m{1cm}m{1cm}m{1cm}}
\shortstack{1\\ 2\\3\\4}
&
\shortstack{1\\2}
&
\shortstack{1\\2\\3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]